# Local broadcast reciever to broadcast when I receive SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a class that extend dialog, that contains a Edittext for Pincode, I have registered a global broadcast to receive the SMS and parse it, and then after getting the Pincode from the message I send another local broadcast with the following code

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction(SMS_RECEIVED);
intent.putExtra(SMS_PIN_CODE,msgBody.substring(msgBody.length() - SMS_PIN_CODE_LENGTH));
mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

and then in my dialog class I have created broadcast receiver to listen to (SMS_RECEIVED) and put the value into the UI as following

```
private BroadcastReceiver                   mPinCodeReceived = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "I'm Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mPincodeEdittext != null) {

                String pinCode = intent
                        .getStringExtra(BillingConstatnts.SMS_PIN_CODE);
                mPincodeEdittext.setText(pinCode);
            }
        }
    };
```

and I have registered this broadcast in the onCreate Method of the dialog class

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mPinCodeReceived,new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED));
```

the problem now that the onReceive method of my local broadcast not called ,so can anyone please tell me what if the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what i do to update me ui when message comes. I get a broadcast from my service thought but that shouldnt be a prob.

```
onResume(){
            registerReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver, new IntentFilter(BackgroundActivity.BROADCAST_BUFFER_SEND_CODE));

    }

// set up broadcast receiver
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastBufferReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent bufferIntent) {
            SendCode.this.LoadMessages(alarmNumber);
        }
    };
```

Comment: no I have already received the sms and parse it, what I want to make if to show it in the UI of my class that inherit Dialog using local broadcast

Comment: delete your register from onCreate and add it to onResume. Try that

Comment: my class extending Dialog class, which has no onResume method

Comment: Not sure if this will work or not, Try to add in new Intent the name of your class. like:Intent broadcast = new Intent("com.example.myclass
");